# Chrome for Mac re-opens old tabs when clicking on a link in Mail, etc

Tags: macos, google-chrome, links

I use Chrome on my Mac and on my PC.  On the Mac (as all of you probably know), it's possible to close all of the Chrome windows/tabs, and Chrome stays running.  AFAIK, this isn't possible on Windows, as closing the last window/tab will shutdown Chrome.

With Chrome on my Mac in this "idle" state, I will very often click on a link in  an email, and Chrome opens up of course.  Besides opening the new link, Chrome almost always opens the previous set of tabs too.  This is annoying to possibly real-trouble, if one of those tabs was an online order, bank transaction, etc.

Note that I do *NOT* have Chrome set to re-open previously-opened tabs when it starts up!  Also, Chrome isn't starting up - it's still running, just in that idle window-less start which Mac apps can do.

Anyone seen anything like this?  Any suggestions on how to stop it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the previous windows were closed, rather than minimised or hidden? I don't see that behaviour here.

Comment: Definitely closed, either by hitting the tab's close button ("X") or the window's close button  (red circle).  I wonder if Yosemite's "App Nap" feature could cause this?  I just turned it off, and need to see how the app behaves now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like turn checking the "Prevent App Nap" option (Finder -> Chrome -> Get Info) fixed this.  YMMV, but this helped me fix this strange behaviour.

Comment: This problem has come back for me, even with this setting turned on.  But, it seems to occur less with this setting turned on.

Answer (score 0):

This has become the bane of my online existence for a week now and I could not find a solution in the world of Google, so I did a little diving into the settings of Chrome and found under Settings > On Startup > Open a specific page ... [Set page] that all those tabs had been erroneous set here.  I removed all the pages from the list and reset to my default page, Google.com.  I quit, restarted, and, voilà, Google w/o the 15 tabs.  The issue has been resolved.

Now, why the tabs had become set to Startup, I do not know, and will it return again in the future, I cannot be certain, but for now there is a way to clean it up.

Comment: My Chrome is set to open the New Tab window, not a set of pages.  This still happens to me, although it's not very often anymore.